# How to make my first element in datalist filtered result , to be selected automatically

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, html-datalist

The following is my code:

```
<input required class="input form-control" type="text" ng-model="select.mySelect" list="bloodgroups" placeholder="Select Blood Group">
<datalist id="bloodgroups" >
    <option ng-repeat="bloodgroup in bloodgroups"> {{bloodgroup.bloodgroups}}
</datalist>
```

Comment: Do you need any further help or clarification? If my answer was helpful please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
$scope.options = [{ name: "a", id: 1 }, { name: "b", id: 2 }];
$scope.selectedOption = $scope.options[1];
```

HTML

```
<select data-ng-options="o.name for o in options" data-ng-model="selectedOption"></select>
```

---

**Additional example:**

This is in the case of retrieving data ([GET](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_requests.htm)) from an external source (url). `Something.thisismydata` is from [factory](https://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider-5f426cfe6b8c).

For `ng-model="select.mySelect"` something like this:

```
$scope.showDataOnSelect = function() {
        var url = "http://example.com/api";
                Something.thisismydata(function(data) {
                    $scope.thisismydata = data;
                    $scope.select.mySelect = $scope.thisismydata[0].id;
                }, url);
            }

$scope.showDataOnSelect();
```